# why data is appearing multiple time after refreshing the button in jdbc swing table?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Here I have created a `JTable` and surround it with `JScrollPane`. I have created an *update* and *refresh* button so that I can refresh and update the values in the data set. But the problem is with the *refresh* button whenever I click the button it appears the data more than one time. Like I have 10 data set after updating the name when I refresh the button it is showing again 10 data means a total of 10+10=20 same types of data.

```
package insertData;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;
//import com.sun.tools.sjavac.pubapi.PubApi;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class Table_formate {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField nametextField;
    private JTextField idtextField;
    private JTextField textFieldname;
    private JTextField textFieldid;
    private JTable table;
    //Connection connection;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Table_formate window = new Table_formate();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Table_formate() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 539);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        nametextField = new JTextField();
        nametextField.setBounds(140, 11, 152, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(nametextField);
        nametextField.setColumns(10);
        
        idtextField = new JTextField();
        idtextField.setColumns(10);
        idtextField.setBounds(140, 68, 152, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(idtextField);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//load driver    
                    java.sql.Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","root");    //Establish connection
                    System.out.println("sucess");
                    
                    String drop="insert into student values(?,?) ";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=((java.sql.Connection) connection).prepareStatement(drop);
                    //System.out.println(ps);
                    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(idtextField.getText()));
                    ps.setString(2, nametextField.getText());
                    
                    System.out.println("id="+idtextField.getText()+"     "+"name="+nametextField.getText());
                    
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();
                    
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(324, 36, 89, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(27, 11, 76, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Id:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(27, 68, 76, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JButton Refreshbtn = new JButton("Refresh");
        Refreshbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    DefaultTableModel tableModel=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    java.sql.Connection  connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","root");
                    java.sql.Statement stmt=((java.sql.Connection) connection).createStatement();
                    System.out.println("connection sucessful");
                    ResultSet rs= ((java.sql.Statement) stmt).executeQuery("select * from student order by id");
                    //PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("select * from student order by id");
                    while ( rs.next()) {
                        String name=rs.getString("name");
                        int id=rs.getInt("id");
                        System.out.println(id+ "name="+name);

                        tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {id,name});
                    } 
                    stmt.close();
                    rs.close();
                    
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
        Refreshbtn.setBounds(122, 139, 89, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Refreshbtn);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(27, 395, 76, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1 = new JLabel("Id:");
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setBounds(27, 452, 76, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1_1);
        
        textFieldname = new JTextField();
        textFieldname.setColumns(10);
        textFieldname.setBounds(140, 395, 152, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldname);
        
        textFieldid = new JTextField();
        textFieldid.setColumns(10);
        textFieldid.setBounds(140, 452, 152, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldid);
        
        JButton btnUpdat = new JButton("update");
        btnUpdat.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String drop="update student set name=? where id=?";
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    java.sql.Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","root");
                    PreparedStatement ps=((java.sql.Connection) connection).prepareStatement(drop);
                    
                    ps.setString(1, textFieldname.getText());
                    ps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(textFieldid.getText()));
                    
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    
                   System.out.println("Record updated");
                    ps.close();
                    
                    Refreshbtn.doClick();
                    
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnUpdat.setBounds(324, 420, 89, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdat);
        
        JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel tableModel=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                int row=table.getSelectedRow();
                
                String name=(String) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 1);
                String id=(String) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                textFieldid.setText(id);
                textFieldname.setText(name);
            }
        });
        btnEdit.setBounds(231, 139, 89, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEdit);
        
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "id", "name"
            }
        ));
        table.setBounds(10, 203, 414, 167);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    }
}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G88Ae.png]

Comment: You're not clearing the table model when you're retrieving the rows from the database.  You're also using absolute positioning on your Swing components, which will lead to problems in the future.  Use Swing [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Hello Dilbert , Could u plz tell me clearly because i am not getting the problem and its solution......

Comment: Method `addRow` (in class `DefaultTableModel`) adds another row to the `JTable`. If you add the same row twice, it will appear twice in the `JTable`. When the user clicks _Refresh_ button, you are adding all the data from the database to the `DefaultTableModel` but the `DefaultTableModel` already contains all the database data so you need to first remove all the data from `DefaultTableModel` before adding the rows from the `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I get the problem and able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Abra mentioned, just clear the contents of your `DefaultTableModel` when refreshing and before adding the new data as follows:

```
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    tableModel.setRowCount(0);
    tableModel.setColumnCount(0);
```

After cleaning the model, populate it again (in this example, adding some random user):

```
model.addColumn("id");
model.addColumn("Name");

Vector<String> userName = new Vector<>();
userName.add(user);
model.addRow(userName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now I get the problem and able to fix it.